# Add existing native project Android in exist project React-Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, integration

I have a native Android project and another iOS, and I need to create a base app in React-Native, so I wanted to put the two native ones inside the React-Native project, is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do React Native Bridge for iOS and Android.


To better understand the concept of react native bridging you can go through below Link.It will provide you basic understanding of react native bridging in Android and IOS.

[Click Here for Explanation](https://hackernoon.com/react-native-bridge-for-ios-and-android-43feb9712fcb) .

Hope it helps !